# wrong SET format. Not sure which one I did wrong

Tags: javascript, firefox, eval, imacros

In short I am trying to do log for an error of my imacros script. If it reach page with a heading Chapter One, means the previous code not working.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=TXT:Chapter<SP>One EXTRACT=TXT


SET !VAR2 EVAL("var text=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; if(text==\"Chapter One\") {iimPlay("code: ADD !extract {{!NOW:yyyymm}}\nADD !extract {{!COL2}}\nADD !extract Cannot<SP>Access<SP>Page\nSAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=logs.txt");iimPlay("0-DeleteAll.iim");};text;")
```

The error pointing at this line.

```
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var text=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; if(text==\"Chapter One\") {iimPlay("code: ADD !extract {{!NOW:yyyymm}}\nADD !extract {{!COL2}}\nADD !extract Cannot<SP>Access<SP>Page\nSAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=logs.txt");iimPlay("0-DeleteAll.iim");};text;")
```

> wrong format of SET command, line 43 (Error code: -910)

Not sure which one.
It must be obvious part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is the result of an unescaped double-quote character inside the EVAL string, specifically at character position 79 on the line containing the SET command. Since the main parameter to EVAL is a string value, any embedded quotes must be escaped using the \ character, e.g. \".

But more importantly, even if you fix the embedded quote characters, this code will not work because you cannot call iimPlay or any other iMacros scripting interface method inside of EVAL. The Javascript engine used by the EVAL command runs in a different context than the main Javascript engine used by the browser, so calls to iimPlay will result in "iimPlay is not defined" (Error code: -1001).